# How to compare contents of several memserves in yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, nested-lists, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have to check few conditions from the yaml file given below:

```
provider: sockets
delayed_free_threads: 0
ATL_threads: 0
ATL_queue_size: 1000
ATL_data_size: 1024
Memservers:
  0:
    memory_type: volatile
    fam_path: /dev/shm/vol_path
    rpc_interface: fam5:8793
    libfabric_port: 7500
    if_device: eth0
  1:
    memory_type: volatile
    fam_path: /dev/shm/vol_path
    rpc_interface: fam4:8793
    libfabric_port: 7500
    if_device: eth1
  2:
    memory_type: volatile
    fam_path: /dev/shm/vol_path
    rpc_interface: fam3:8793
    libfabric_port: 7500
    if_device: eth1
```

Here are the conditions that I want to check:
1.If the rpc_interface is same.
2.If rpc_interface is same, is fam_path same?
3.If rpc_interface is same, is libabric_port same?

Here's the code that i tried:

```
def compare():
    host_port = {}
    fam_path_list = {}
    libabric_port_list ={}
    file_in = Path(r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\toold\fam_memoryserver_config.yaml')
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')  
    data = yaml.load(file_in)
    print(data.values())
    for machine, config in data.values():
            if 'rpc_interface' not in config: 
                print(f'machine {machine} has no "rpc_interface"');
                sys.exit(1)
            else:
                host_port.setdefault(con['rpc_interface'], set()).add(machine)
                fam_path_list.setdefault(config['fam_path'], set()).add(machine)
                libabric_port_list.setdefault(config['libfabric_port'], set()).add(machine)
    # check if host_port has any values that have more than one machine
    for hp, machine_nrs in host_port.items():
        if len(machine_nrs) == 1:
            continue
        j=[str(x) for x in machine_nrs]
        print(f'Found {hp} in machines: {", ".join(j)}')
   
    for hp, machine_nrs in fam_path_list.items():
        if len(machine_nrs) == 1:
            continue
        k=[str(x) for x in machine_nrs]
        print(f'Found {hp} in machines: {", ".join(k)}')

    for hp, machine_nrs in libabric_port_list.items():
        if len(machine_nrs) == 1:
           continue
        l=[str(x) for x in machine_nrs]
        print(f'Found {hp} in machines: {", ".join([str(x) for x in machine_nrs])}')

    def removeElements(j, k):
        return ', '.join(map(str, j)) in ', '.join(map(str, k))

    if (removeElements(j, k)==True) :
        print(f'The memory servers {j}, have the same fam_path, hence Validation failed!')
    else:
        print('Only the rpc_interface of the machines are same, hence Validation failed!')
 

    def removeElements(j, l):
        return ', '.join(map(str, j)) in ', '.join(map(str, l))

    if (removeElements(j, l)==True) :
        print(f'The memory servers {j}, have the same libfabric_port, hence Validation failed!')
        
    else:
        print('Only the rpc_interface of the machines are same, hence Validation failed!')

compare()
```

But the eror I am getting is :

```
for machine, config in data.values():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Please let me know how to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is a dict (loaded from the root-level mapping in your YAML). If you iterate over `data.values()` you only get the values, i.e. `sockets`, `0`, etc. YOu cannot assign that to two variables.

Since you are testing on `rpc_interface` you probably want to do:

```
for machine, config in data['Memservers'].items():
```